# Input string tokens from text file's lines into array, then output as collection of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, iterator

I want to read a text file, line by line. Each line in the text file contains 5 strings - separated by " ". After split each string token from the line, I must put each token into an array. Only then I create an arraylist of such arrays.

I'm having problems printing the ArrayList, as the loop appears to run infinitely and printing only the strings on last line (last array) in the file.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test 
{
    static File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Nuno\\Documents\\test_file.txt");          //source file

    private static String[] values = new String[4];                                    //array of 5 values (numbers as string values)
    private static final List<String[]> ListOfArrayOfValues = new ArrayList<>();       //ArrayList of String arrays

    public static void ReadWriteArrayList()
    {
        String lines;                                                           //each line on file, that contains 5 nums

        try                                                                     //read data from file and create ArrayList containing arrays of 5 strings
        {   
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);                       //reads file in default encoding
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);       //always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader
            //lines = bufferReader.readLine();                                  //this assignment must be argument to while loop, otherwise goes in infinite loop 
            while((lines = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)       
            {
                values = lines.split(" ");                                      //assign each string token in the line (split by space) to an ARRAY of Strings
                ListOfArrayOfValues.add(values);                                //add each array to the arraylist
            }
            bufferReader.close();                                               //always close file after reading
        }catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataLott.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //read ArrayList and output arrays (drawings) to screen
        ListIterator<String[]> outputArrayOfValues = ListOfArrayOfValues.listIterator();    //iterator for ArrayList
        while(outputArrayOfValues.hasNext())                                                //iterate through ArrayList
        {
            for(String num : values)                                            //loop each array in ArrayList
            {
                System.out.println(num + " ");                                  //print each number in a array (i.e. each number in a drawing)
            }
        }
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ReadWriteArrayList();
    }

}
```

The output should look like the original file, such as:

```
10 28 31 33 34
02 15 20 29 31
10 19 23 25 34
03 04 08 33 34
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
03 
04 
08 
33 
34 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the array from the iterator within the loop, and change how you print your values:

```
ListIterator<String[]> outputArrayOfValues = ListOfArrayOfValues.listIterator();
while(outputArrayOfValues.hasNext())                                                    {

    // add this line to get the values from the current item in the iterator
    String[] rowValues = outputArrayOfValues.next();

    for(String num : rowValues)                                                    
    {
        //  change this line to not print a carriage return
        System.out.print(num + " ");                                  
    }

    // print the carriage return here
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using  System.out.print(num + " "); (without the ln) in the inner loop and then a system.out.println("") in the outer while loop. (the ln is for newline).